# @font-face vertical align issue in firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, font-face, truetype

Hi i have an issue with font which is rendering as like having a margin at the top and same font is working fine in all other browsers (I have tested in windows and ubuntu).

My problem seems to be like

[image]

And in other browsers

[image]

I have used font squirrel for generating font-face and here is the code that it has generated

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'garrisons';
    src:url('../fonts/garrisons-regular-webfont.ttf');
    src: url('../fonts/garrisons-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/garrisons-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/garrisons-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/garrisons-regular-webfont.svg#garrison_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height:30px;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'garrisonsb';
    src: url('../fonts/garrisons-bold-webfont.ttf');
    src: url('../fonts/garrisons-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/garrisons-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/garrisons-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/garrisons-bold-webfont.svg#garrison_sansbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

What may be the possible solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Those different font formats you provided render differently in different browsers. For example, IE supports .eot whereas Chrome supports .ttf . The difference between browsers means that you will have to find a happy medium when it comes to providing solution for different browser variations.

So maybe add more of a bottom margin so it doesn't look foolish on one type of browser. Its an inexact process, but whatever result you think works best for all browsers is often the best route of action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ya that may be final solution if nothing else works. But is there any standard to deal with cross browser compatibility or something like that to solve this issue?

Comment: The extensive cross browser solution would be to go in and edit the fonts yourself and figure out how to edit them so they will render them similarly across browsers. In your case, I don't know if that is possible or even worth it.

Another alternative is to use strictly svgs, but I don't know how ubiquitous support is across browsers